# Mass edit reject - why?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have proposed a few edits, and all of them, even the most worthy of being accepted got rejected for an ambiguous reason : "The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing."

Some of those edits were :

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/337217
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/337218
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/337219
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/337220 (this one got approved by post owner later)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/337221

When I see the time of review, it makes me think that the reviewer ***didn't even bother to read*** what I've done, they just mass-rejected. When I see the review time for review 337217, I see "30 mins ago"; and when I check for review 337221, I also see "30 mins ago"...

(Meaning that the reviewer reviewed 5 edits in less than 1 minute)

[image]

I have read [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4151/why-are-my-edits-rejected-and-why-am-i-suspended-from-editing) awesome post on this subject by @Allan but according to it, my edits could well have been approved... They were made on posts or threads that were on the home page in the past seven days, and they do not seem to be unnecessary or harmful.

And here we go again, I had those posts pinned for me to edit them because I was blocked for editing for the last seven days (other rejected edits...), and here I am, about one hour after having been freed from my ban, I'm blocked again! :(

And, with this, I'm also blocked from reviewing! :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reviewer was me (which is obvious from the screenshot).

If you look at the two screenshots and at Allan's post you link to:

- 337217 fits the "Edits greater than 5 years will likely be rejected" rule,
- for 337221, "Edit between 1 and 5 years I take on a case by case basis" applies and, to be honest, while I strongly support the use of neutral pronouns in posts, I consider it a waste of time to go through *all* old posts to change "he" or "she" into "they".

Please keep in mind that each of your edits

- takes your time
- takes the time of at least two reviewers
- bounces the question back onto the front page

So make edits which count and make a difference on the site by improving critical things. As a rule of thumb, focus on recent posts. As a more general rule of thumb, the older the post, the more substantial the edit should be.

PS: I've removed the ban.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I just have things to say about the "5 years rule" an the "1-5 years rule". (1) all posts mentioned (except 337221) are in a thread (question+answer(s)) that was itself bumped to the front page in the past 7 days - 337217's thread contained [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366852/489896) which was bumped on May 13th. Then here comes a new sub-question : *Are those "rules" applying if the thread was already "bumped" quite recently?* - I was taking the answer to this as granted ("no") but it seems that I'm mistaken?

Comment: @Thinkr All of these rules are to be taken with a grant of salt for sure, and there for sure are exceptions. But why try to find the hard boundary here and not focus on things which are worth editing and well within "age of post" limits? I think I said this already before: there is no need to use *all* your edits every day, you are also way past the "new user desperate to ramp up reputation" mark :-)

Comment: Ah, yeah, you said this for upvotes when I first came to AD. I just have another question (sorry, again) : I have seen [a post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458800/2013-imac-with-apfs-fusion-drive-fails-to-boot-how-to-recover-data/459970#459970) in "First answers" about 10-20 mins ago with a few formatting improvements that could be done, can I just edit it to improve the formatting or do I just leave it like that? I'm not so sure what to do with it (even more if it's being menaced by deletion). Thanks ;D

Comment: @thinkr That looks like a good post to edit, most likely all posts in the First Question/Answer queue are good candidates. Having more experienced people look at first posts to help with formatting, clarity etc. is exactly the reason for having these review queues in the first place.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help provided. I'm editing it right now! :)

Comment: Hey again, I'm not here to complain but it seems that some users are not agreeing with you. I let you see the comments and the timeline on the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458800/2013-imac-with-apfs-fusion-drive-fails-to-boot-how-to-recover-data/459970#459970) we were talking about. :)

Comment: @thinkr that was a follow-up question posted as an answer. Usually flagging them is better than editing, unless editing can turn them into an actual answer.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for thr clarification! :)