# Comments on Review Actions

Tags: discussion, comments, suggested-edits, policy

My edit was rejected and I posted a comment on the related question/answer.

I was then told I shouldn’t do this.  I thought comments were for clarifications.

What’s the proper etiquette  here?

Answer (score 4):

<sup>This post is intended to address a particular behavior, not a particular user.</sup>

### Comments should NOT be placed on questions/answers regarding related review actions taken.

After rejecting an edit, shortly thereafter, I received a comment on the answer:

> Why reject an edit that actually improved the post's phrasing?

#### This is wholly the incorrect venue for this type of discourse.

If there is an issue with the actions of another user, the proper place to bring this up is in chat or here on Meta, not on the questions/answer comments.  Keep in mind, the OP will get inundated with all of the chat content totally unrelated to their actual question.  I know I don’t like seeing an Inbox with a double digit badge of unread messages only to find it’s all irrelevant chatter.

#### Why exactly did I reject the edit?

**Primarily, it changed what I was trying to say**.  I try to evaluate ***all*** edits (not just my own) objectively through the lens of improving the post.  That said, I will object to superfluous  edits because it appears nothing more than a thesaurus was utilized or tense was changed.  I rejected another edit in the queue because it changed a bulleted list to an enumerated one that ultimately did nothing to improve a ~2yr old post.

I rejected the edit because it did two things:

- changed the intent conveyed by my wording
- made incorrect edits

I’m pretty open with my reasoning behind my rejection/approval reasoning and I’ve posted it [here on Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4152/119271) as a method of full disclosure.

I didn’t post “edits will be rejected that change the author’s intent” because it’s quite literally one of the reasons presented by the review system.

#### TL;DR

Comments are for clarifications, questions, issues with the *post* not irrelevant discourse.  We’ve all made this mistake (your truly included) but it’s becoming much more pronounced.  The reason why is a different discussion altogether.  That said, comments need to be relevant to the post and limited in scope. Anything past that should be addressed in chat or on Meta.

With respect to editing: do **not** change people’s wording because it has a significant chance of changing their intent.  Making edits to fix grammar is a delicate balance between fixing wording for  readability and changing the meaning; it’s not fixing typos or formatting.

Comment: That edit @nohillside, is not without a massive sense of irony!

Comment: Absolutely! Good points in your answer here actually, thanks for documenting this.